# Is there a way to have a table cell stay fixed at a given height AND enable word-wrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to place room labels at different locations on a map. The rooms are of variable heights and so the "height" attribute is set in the JavaScript/React code for each room label.

My problem is that if I want the height of the cell *not* to expand with the length of longer strings, I have to turn off word-wrap. However, I would like to wrap words and have many lines of the name, so long as it does not exceed the height I set.

Is there a way to do this? Here's my current set up, which just stretches to display the whole string.

React:

```
return <div className={cx('roomLabelContainer')}
  style={{left: startX, top: startY, width: width, height: height}}>
  <table className={cx('roomLabel')}>
    {this.props.roomLabelName}
  </table>
</div>;
```

CSS:

```
.roomLabelContainer {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.roomLabel {
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since table rows wont respect a `max-height` property (per W3C spec) a possible solution is to wrap your cell contents in a div and use that to constrain the row.

```
<td class="roomLabel"><div class="constrain">text...</div></td>
```

And the CSS

```
.constrain {
  position: relative;
  max-height: /* choose */;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```